# Magento 2 - force customer browsers to re-laod Cache fresh

Tags: magento2, cache

we have set up a new Magento 2.3.1 page. We are using Lite Mage Cache.

We were live, but had to do several changes and to deploy the page new multiple times.

Now it seems, that several of our clients are facing problems with the styles, CSS and the Cache in general. Not all, but some.

Does anyone of you know, if there is any way, that I can force that my shop needs to be loaded completely new from the scratch in the clients browsers?

Is there any time stamp, any little code snippet or something like that, which I can include, so that the page will load for all clients completely fresh?

Any help here is highly appreciated.

Warm regards and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento has feature built in

In order to enable versions support for static content in Magento 2 the Sign Static Files field should be enabled. Navigate to Magento Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer. Change Sign Static Files setting to “Yes” and hit “Save Config” button. Make sure to flush cache after.

Any static deployment followed by cache flush should bump number and force browser client to fetch updated version.

Comment: Hi Dominic, that sounds reasonable. However in my Magento version 2.3.1  Magento Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced I do not see -> Developer . See here: https://pasteboard.co/ICXZF06.jpg Do you have any idea, how to feature the same?

Comment: Found out. In Develpoper Mode it shows. We were in production mode.

Comment: It seems there are several possibilities of "Cache Busting". There is also a feee extension for this https://marketplace.magento.com/absolute-magento2-cache-bust.html <-- does anyone have experience with this?